# Running Functions Contained In String In Python

Tags: python, string, function

So if I have a string:

```
test = "blah add(2, 3) blah add(5, 3)"
```

How could I process the functions in the string (supposing `add()` adds the numbers, I know there is "+") so it becomes:

```
"blah 5 blah 8"
```

I have tried running through the string looking for open brackets "(" but that didn't work very well.

Comment: so, string will contain only `add` function?

Comment: No, it should process any function, the best thing I want is that I could just add a new function to the string and it will work just like that, but anything else is just as good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dangerous to execute arbitrary code, but assuming the functions are defined you can `eval` the function matches from `re.finditer()`:

```
In [0]:
import re
def add(a, b):
    return a+b

s = "fred add(1, 2) fred add(1,8)"
{m.group(): eval(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r"\w+\s?\(.*?\)", s)}

Out[0]:
{'add(1, 2)': 3, 'add(1,8)': 9}
```

Comment: This is perfect besides two things, it gets rid of "fred", and how do I convert "{'add(1, 2)': 3, 'add(1,8)': 9}" to "3 9"?

Comment: `' '.join(str(eval(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r"\w+\s?\(.*?\)", s)))`

Comment: You can also replace in `s`, e.g. `for m in re.finditer(...): s = s.replace(m.group(), str(eval(m.group())))`

Comment: What? Where do I put this?

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the solution I need!

Comment: Quick question, this doesn't work with built-in python functions, because it looks to a custom function, could I specify a list of functions that it will process? Or just not process built-in functions? Thanks.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work with builtin-functions... `eval(min(1,2))` should return `1`.

Comment: print(ProcessString("'lol'.split(' ')")) (where ProcessString() is the code you gave) NameError: name 'split' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Does it serve your need?

```
import re

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

test = "blah add(2, 3) blah add(5, 3)"
m = re.findall(r"add\((.*?)\)", test)

for item in m:
    numbers = item.split(',')
    val = add(int(numbers[0].strip()), int(numbers[1].strip()))
    test = test.replace('add(' + item + ')', str(val))

print(test)
```

Output:

```
blah 5 blah 8
```

Comment: How can I process the functions when the string contains quotes? It ends the string. Also, this only works for "add()"

Comment: @CUZLOCKED modify the regular expression. you can do whatever you need using regexp. I encourage you to study regular expression.